# Improved RFC 1951 Deflate compression

Tags: c#, compression, pdf

I have substantially revised my [earlier implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210757/rfc-1951-deflate-compression), it now seems to be competitive with the standard C# ZLib implementation, increasing compression while being faster for moderate length inputs, and slightly slower for large inputs ( data dependent ) - see long initial comment below for details.

It may also be competitive with google's [Zopfli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopfli), which is much slower but which aims to maximise compression with a sophisticated algorithm to divide the input into blocks.

The code below chooses a blocksize ( for each individual block ) according to whether a larger blocksize improves compression.

After a fair bit of consideration, I decided against using _ for private field names, except if there is a clash with a property name ( as in the Heap class below ). I also opened a [github account](https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf) with my C# code for writing PDF files, which is my use for the code below.

I don't have specific questions for review, but would be interested in alternative ideas for dividing the input into blocks.

```
namespace Pdf {

/* RFC 1951 compression ( https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt ) aims to compress a stream of bytes using :

   (1) LZ77 matching, where if an input sequences of at least 3 bytes re-occurs, it may be coded 
       as a <length,distance> pointer.

   (2) Huffman coding, where variable length codes are used, with more frequently used symbols encoded in less bits.

   The input may be split into blocks, a new block introduces a new set of Huffman codes. The choice of block 
   boundaries can affect compression. The method used to determine the block size is as follows:

   (1) The size of the next block to be output is set to an initial value.

   (2) A comparison is made between encoding two blocks of this size, or a double-length block.

   (3) If the double-length encoding is better, that becomes the block size, and the process repeats.

   LZ77 compression is implemented as suggested in the standard, although no attempt is made to
   truncate searches ( except searches terminate when the distance limit of 32k bytes is reached ).

   Only dynamic huffman blocks are used, no attempt is made to use Fixed or Copy blocks.

   Deflator ( this code) typically achieves better compression than ZLib ( http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm 
   via https://zlib.net/, default settings ) by a few percent, and is faster on small inputs, but slower 
   on large inputs ( perhaps due to searches not being truncated ).

   For example, compressing a font file FreeSans.ttf ( 264,072 bytes ), Zlib output is 148,324 bytes
   in 44 milliseconds, whereas Deflator output is 144,289 bytes, 4,035 bytes smaller, in 59 milliseconds.

   Compressing a C# source file of 19,483 bytes, Zlib output size was 5,965 bytes in 27 milliseconds, 
   whereas Deflator output was 5,890 bytes, 75 bytes smaller, in 16 milliseconds.

   Sample usage:

   byte [] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   var mbs = new MemoryBitStream();
   Deflator.Deflate( data, mbs, 1 );
   byte [] deflated_data = mbs.ToArray();

   The MemoryBitStream may alternatively be copied to a stream, this may be useful when writing PDF files ( the intended use case ).

   Auxiliary top level classes/structs ( included in this file ): 
   *  OutBitStream.
   *  MemoryBitStream : an implementation of OutBitStream.
   *  HuffmanCoding calculates Huffman codes.
   *  Heap : used to implemnt HuffmanCoding.
*/   

sealed class Deflator 
{
  public static void Deflate( byte [] input, OutBitStream output, int format )
  {
    Deflator d = new Deflator( input, output );
    if ( format == 1 ) output.WriteBits( 16, 0x9c78 ); // RFC 1950 bytes.
    d.FindMatches( input );
    d.Buffered = input.Length;
    while ( !d.OutputBlock( true ) );
    if ( format == 1 )
    { 
      output.Pad( 8 );
      output.WriteBits( 32, Adler32( input ) ); // RFC 1950 checksum. 
    }  
  }

  // Private constants.

  // RFC 1951 limits.
  private const int MinMatch = 3;
  private const int MaxMatch = 258;
  private const int MaxDistance = 0x8000;

  private const int StartBlockSize = 0x1000; // Initial blocksize, actual may be larger or smaller. Need not be power of two.
  private const bool DynamicBlockSize = true; 
  private const int MaxBufferSize = 0x8000; // Must be power of 2.

  // Instead of initialising LZ77 hashTable and link arrays to -(MaxDistance+1), EncodePosition 
  // is added when storing a value and subtracted when retrieving a value.
  // This means a default value of 0 will always be more distant than MaxDistance.
  private const int EncodePosition = MaxDistance + 1;

  // Private fields.

  private byte [] Input;
  private OutBitStream Output;

  private int Buffered; // How many Input bytes have been processed to intermediate buffer.
  private int Finished; // How many Input bytes have been written to Output.

  // Intermediate circular buffer for storing LZ77 matches.
  private int    [] PositionBuffer;
  private ushort [] LengthBuffer;
  private ushort [] DistanceBuffer;
  private int BufferMask;
  private int BufferWrite, BufferRead; // Indexes for writing and reading.

  // Private functions and classes.

  private Deflator( byte [] input, OutBitStream output )
  { 
    Input = input; 
    Output = output; 

    int bufferSize = CalcBufferSize( input.Length / 3, MaxBufferSize );
    PositionBuffer = new int[ bufferSize ];
    LengthBuffer   = new ushort[ bufferSize ];
    DistanceBuffer = new ushort[ bufferSize ];   
    BufferMask = bufferSize - 1; 
  }

  public static int CalcBufferSize( int n, int max )
  // Calculates a power of 2 >= n, but not more than max.
  {
    if ( n >= max ) return max;
    int result = 1;
    while ( result < n ) result = result << 1;
    return result;
  }

  private void FindMatches( byte [] input ) // LZ77 compression.
  {
    if ( input.Length < MinMatch ) return;
    int limit = input.Length - 2;

    int hashShift = CalcHashShift( limit * 2 );
    uint hashMask = ( 1u << ( MinMatch * hashShift ) ) - 1;

    int [] hashTable = new int[ hashMask + 1 ];
    int [] link = new int[ limit ];

    int position = 0; // position in input.
    uint hash = ( (uint)input[ 0 ] << hashShift ) + input[ 1 ];

    while ( position < limit )
    {
      hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;        
      int hashEntry = hashTable[ hash ];
      hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
      if ( position >= hashEntry ) // Equivalent to position - ( hashEntry - EncodePosition ) > MaxDistance.
      {
         position += 1;
         continue;
      }
      link[ position ] = hashEntry;

      int distance, match = BestMatch( input, link, hashEntry - EncodePosition, position, out distance );
      position += 1;
      if ( match < MinMatch ) continue;

      // "Lazy matching" RFC 1951 p.15 : if there are overlapping matches, there is a choice over which of the match to use.
      // Example: "abc012bc345.... abc345". Here abc345 can be encoded as either [abc][345] or as a[bc345].
      // Since a range typically needs more bits to encode than a single literal, choose the latter.
      while ( position < limit ) 
      {
        hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;          
        hashEntry = hashTable[ hash ];
        hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
        if ( position >= hashEntry ) break;
        link[ position ] = hashEntry;

        int distance2, match2 = BestMatch( input, link, hashEntry - EncodePosition, position, out distance2 );
        if ( match2 > match || match2 == match && distance2 < distance )
        {
          match = match2;
          distance = distance2;
          position += 1;
        }
        else break;
      }

      int copyEnd = SaveMatch( position - 1, match, distance );
      if ( copyEnd > limit ) copyEnd = limit;

      position += 1;

      // Advance to end of copied section.
      while ( position < copyEnd )
      { 
        hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;
        link[ position ] = hashTable[ hash ];
        hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
        position += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  private static int BestMatch( byte [] input, int [] link, int oldPosition, int position, out int distance )
  { 
    int avail = input.Length - position;
    if ( avail > MaxMatch ) avail = MaxMatch;

    int bestMatch = 0, bestDistance = 0;

    while ( true )
    { 
      if ( input[ position + bestMatch ] == input[ oldPosition + bestMatch ] )
      {
        int match = MatchLength( input, position, oldPosition );
        if ( match > bestMatch )
        {
          bestMatch = match;
          bestDistance = position - oldPosition;
          if ( bestMatch == avail ) break;
        }
      }
      oldPosition = link[ oldPosition ];
      if ( position >= oldPosition ) break;
      oldPosition -= EncodePosition;
    }
    distance = bestDistance;
    return bestMatch;
  }

  private static int MatchLength( byte [] input, int p, int q )
  {
    int end = input.Length;
    if ( end > p + MaxMatch ) end = p + MaxMatch;
    int pstart = p;
    while ( p < end && input[ p ] == input [ q ] )
    {
      p += 1;
      q += 1;
    }
    return p - pstart;
  }

  private static int CalcHashShift( int n )
  {
    int p = 1;
    int result = 0;
    while ( n > p ) 
    {
      p = p << MinMatch;
      result += 1;
      if ( result == 6 ) break;
    }
    return result;
  } 

  private int SaveMatch ( int position, int length, int distance )
  // Called from FindMatches to save a <length,distance> match. Returns position + length.
  {
    // System.Console.WriteLine( "SaveMatch at " + position + " length=" + length + " distance=" + distance );
    int i = BufferWrite;
    PositionBuffer[ i ] = position;
    LengthBuffer[ i ] = (ushort) length;
    DistanceBuffer[ i ] = (ushort) distance;
    i = ( i + 1 ) & BufferMask;
    if ( i == BufferRead ) OutputBlock( false );
    BufferWrite = i;
    position += length;
    Buffered = position;
    return position;
  }

  private bool OutputBlock( bool last )
  {
    int blockSize = Buffered - Finished; // Uncompressed size in bytes.

    if ( blockSize > StartBlockSize ) 
    {
      blockSize = ( last && blockSize < StartBlockSize*2 ) ? blockSize >> 1 : StartBlockSize;
    }

    Block b;
    int bits; // Compressed size in bits.

    // While block construction fails, reduce blockSize.
    while ( true )
    {
      b = new Block( this, blockSize, null, out bits );
      if ( bits >= 0 ) break;
      blockSize -= blockSize / 3;
    }     

    // Investigate larger block size.
    while ( b.End < Buffered && DynamicBlockSize ) 
    {
      // b2 is a block which starts just after b.
      int bits2; Block b2 = new Block( this, blockSize, b, out bits2 );
      if ( bits2 < 0 ) break;

      // b3 is the block which encodes b and b2 together.
      int bits3; Block b3 = new Block( this, b2.End - b.Start, null, out bits3 );
      if ( bits3 < 0 ) break;

      if ( bits3 > bits + bits2 ) break;

      bits = bits3;
      b = b3;
      blockSize += blockSize; 
    }      

    // Output the block.
    if ( b.End < Buffered ) last = false;
    b.WriteBlock( this, last );  
    return last;
  }

  public static uint Adler32( byte [] b ) // Checksum function per RFC 1950.
  {
    uint s1 = 1, s2 = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < b.Length; i += 1 )
    {
      s1 = ( s1 + b[ i ] ) % 65521;
      s2 = ( s2 + s1 ) % 65521;
    }
    return s2 * 65536 + s1;    
  }

  private class Block
  {
    public readonly int Start, End; // Range of input encoded.

    public Block( Deflator d, int blockSize, Block previous, out int bits )
    // The block is not immediately output, to allow caller to try different block sizes.
    // Instead, the number of bits neeed to encoded the block is returned ( excluding "extra" bits ).
    {
      Output = d.Output;
      bits = -1;

      if ( previous == null )
      {
        Start = d.Finished;
        BufferStart = d.BufferRead;
      }
      else
      {
        Start = previous.End;
        BufferStart = previous.BufferEnd;
      }

      int avail = d.Buffered - Start;
      if ( blockSize > avail ) blockSize = avail;

      End = TallyFrequencies( d, blockSize );
      Lit.Used[ 256 ] += 1; // End of block code.

      if ( Lit.ComputeCodes() || Dist.ComputeCodes() ) return;

      if ( Dist.Count == 0 ) Dist.Count = 1;

      // Compute length encoding.
      DoLengthPass( 1 );
      if ( Len.ComputeCodes() ) return;

      // The length codes are permuted before being stored ( so that # of trailing zeroes is likely to be more ).
      Len.Count = 19; while ( Len.Count > 4 && Len.Bits[ ClenAlphabet[ Len.Count - 1 ] ] == 0 ) Len.Count -= 1;

      bits = 17 + 3 * Len.Count + Len.Total() + Lit.Total() + Dist.Total();
    }

    public void WriteBlock( Deflator d, bool last )
    {
      OutBitStream output = Output;
      output.WriteBits( 1, last ? 1u : 0u );
      output.WriteBits( 2, 2 );
      output.WriteBits( 5, (uint)( Lit.Count - 257 ) ); 
      output.WriteBits( 5, (uint)( Dist.Count - 1 ) ); 
      output.WriteBits( 4, (uint)( Len.Count - 4 ) );

      for ( int i = 0; i < Len.Count; i += 1 ) 
        output.WriteBits( 3, Len.Bits[ ClenAlphabet[ i ] ] );

      DoLengthPass( 2 );
      PutCodes( d );
      output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ 256 ], Lit.Codes[ 256 ] ); // End of block code
    }

    // Block private fields and constants.

    private OutBitStream Output;
    private int BufferStart, BufferEnd;

    // Huffman codings : Lit = Literal or Match Code, Dist = Distance code, Len = Length code.
    HuffmanCoding Lit = new HuffmanCoding(15,288), Dist = new HuffmanCoding(15,32), Len = new HuffmanCoding(7,19);

    // Counts for code length encoding.
    private int LengthPass, PreviousLength, ZeroRun, Repeat;

    // RFC 1951 constants.
    private readonly static byte [] ClenAlphabet = { 16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15 };
    private readonly static byte [] MatchExtra = { 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 0 };
    private readonly static ushort [] MatchOff = { 3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10, 11,13,15,17, 19,23,27,31, 35,43,51,59, 67,83,99,115, 
      131,163,195,227, 258, 0xffff };
    private readonly static byte [] DistExtra = { 0,0,0,0, 1,1,2,2, 3,3,4,4, 5,5,6,6, 7,7,8,8, 9,9,10,10, 11,11,12,12, 13,13 };
    private readonly static ushort [] DistOff = { 1,2,3,4, 5,7,9,13, 17,25,33,49, 65,97,129,193, 257,385,513,769, 
      1025,1537,2049,3073, 4097,6145,8193,12289, 16385,24577, 0xffff };

    // Block private functions.

    private int TallyFrequencies( Deflator d, int blockSize )
    {
      int position = Start;
      int end = position + blockSize;

      int bufferRead = BufferStart;
      while ( position < end && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        if ( matchPosition >= end ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        bufferRead = ( bufferRead + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        byte [] input = d.Input;
        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          Lit.Used[ input[ position ] ] += 1;
          position += 1;
        }

        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        Lit.Used[ 257 + mc ] += 1;
        Dist.Used[ dc ] += 1;     
      }

      while ( position < end ) 
      {
        Lit.Used[ d.Input[ position ] ] += 1;
        position += 1;
      }

      BufferEnd = bufferRead;
      return position;
    }

    private void PutCodes( Deflator d )
    {
      byte [] input = d.Input;
      OutBitStream output = d.Output;

      int position = Start;
      int bufferRead = BufferStart;

      while ( position < End && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];

        if ( matchPosition >= End ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead  ]; 

        bufferRead = ( bufferRead  + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          byte b = d.Input[ position ];
          output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ b ], Lit.Codes[ b ] );
          position += 1;
        }  
        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ], Lit.Codes[ 257 + mc ] );
        output.WriteBits( MatchExtra[ mc ], (uint)(length-MatchOff[ mc ] ) );
        output.WriteBits( Dist.Bits[ dc ], Dist.Codes[ dc ] );
        output.WriteBits( DistExtra[ dc ], (uint)(distance-DistOff[ dc ] ) );    
      }

      while ( position < End ) 
      {
        byte b = input[ position ];
        output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ b ], Lit.Codes[ b ] );
        position += 1;
      }  

      d.BufferRead = bufferRead;
      d.Finished = position;
    }

    // Run length encoding of code lengths - RFC 1951, page 13.

    private void DoLengthPass( int pass )
    {
      LengthPass = pass; 
      EncodeLengths( Lit.Count, Lit.Bits, true );     
      EncodeLengths( Dist.Count, Dist.Bits, false );
    }

    private void PutLength( int code ) 
    { 
      if ( LengthPass == 1 ) 
        Len.Used[ code ] += 1; 
      else 
        Output.WriteBits( Len.Bits[ code ], Len.Codes[ code ] ); 
    }

    private void EncodeLengths( int n, byte [] lengths, bool isLit )
    {
      if ( isLit ) 
      { 
        PreviousLength = 0; 
        ZeroRun = 0; 
        Repeat = 0; 
      }
      for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 1 )
      {
        int length = lengths[ i ];
        if ( length == 0 )
        { 
          EncodeRepeat(); 
          ZeroRun += 1; 
          PreviousLength = 0; 
        }
        else if ( length == PreviousLength ) 
        {
          Repeat += 1;
        }
        else 
        { 
          EncodeZeroRun(); 
          EncodeRepeat(); 
          PutLength( length ); 
          PreviousLength = length; 
        }
      }      
      if ( !isLit ) 
      { 
        EncodeZeroRun(); 
        EncodeRepeat();
      }
    }

    private void EncodeRepeat()
    {
      while ( Repeat > 0 )
      {
        if ( Repeat < 3 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( PreviousLength ); 
          Repeat -= 1; 
        }
        else 
        { 
          int x = Repeat; 
          if ( x > 6 ) x = 6; 
          PutLength( 16 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 )
          { 
            Output.WriteBits( 2, (uint)( x - 3 ) ); 
          }
          Repeat -= x;  
        }
      }
    }

    private void EncodeZeroRun()
    {
      while ( ZeroRun > 0 )
      {
        if ( ZeroRun < 3 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( 0 ); 
          ZeroRun -= 1; 
        }
        else if ( ZeroRun < 11 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( 17 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 ) Output.WriteBits( 3, (uint)( ZeroRun - 3 ) ); 
          ZeroRun = 0;  
        }
        else 
        { 
          int x = ZeroRun; 
          if ( x > 138 ) x = 138; 
          PutLength( 18 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 ) Output.WriteBits( 7, (uint)( x - 11 ) ); 
          ZeroRun -= x; 
        }
      }
    }
  } // end class Block

} // end class Deflator


// ******************************************************************************

struct HuffmanCoding // Variable length coding.
{
  public int Count; // Number of used symbols.
  public int [] Used; // Count of how many times a symbol is used in the block being encoded.
  public byte [] Bits; // Number of bits used to encode a symbol.
  public ushort [] Codes; // Huffman code for a symbol ( bit 0 is most significant ).
  private int Limit; // Maxiumum number of bits for a code.

  public HuffmanCoding( int limit, int symbols )
  {
    Limit = limit;
    Count = symbols;
    Used = new int[ symbols ];
    Bits = new byte[ symbols ];
    Codes = new ushort[ symbols ];
  }

  public int Total()
  {
    int result = 0, count = Count;
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i += 1 ) 
      result += Used[i] * Bits[i];
    return result;
  }

  public bool ComputeCodes() // returns true if Limit is exceeded.
  {
    int count = Count;

    Heap<TreeNode> heap = new Heap<TreeNode>( count, TreeNode.LessThan );

    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 )
    {
      int used = Used[ i ];
      if ( used > 0 ) heap.Insert( new Leaf( (ushort)i, used ) );
    }

    int maxBits = 0;

    if ( heap.Count == 1 )
    { 
      heap.Remove().GetBits( Bits, 1 );
      maxBits = 1;
    }
    else if ( heap.Count > 1 )
    {
      do // Keep pairing the lowest frequency TreeNodes.
      {
        heap.Insert( new Branch( heap.Remove(), heap.Remove() ) );
      }  while ( heap.Count > 1 );

      TreeNode root = heap.Remove();
      maxBits = root.Depth;
      if ( maxBits > Limit ) return true;
      root.GetBits( Bits, 0 ); // Walk the tree to find the code lengths (Bits).
    }

    // Compute codes, code below is from RFC 1951 page 7.

    int [] bl_count = new int[ maxBits + 1 ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i += 1 ) bl_count[ Bits[ i ] ] += 1;

    int [] next_code = new int[ maxBits + 1 ];
    int code = 0; bl_count[ 0 ] = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxBits; i += 1 ) 
    {
      code = ( code + bl_count[ i ] ) << 1;
      next_code[ i+1 ] = code;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i += 1 ) 
    {
      int length = Bits[ i ];
      if ( length != 0 ) 
      {
        Codes[ i ] = (ushort)Reverse( next_code[ length ], length );
        next_code[ length ] += 1;
      }
    }

    // Reduce count if there are unused symbols.
    while ( count > 0 && Bits[ count - 1 ] == 0 ) count -= 1;
    Count = count;

    //System.Console.WriteLine( "HuffEncoder.ComputeCodes" );
    //    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i += 1 ) if ( Bits[ i ] > 0 )
    //      System.Console.WriteLine( "i=" + i + " len=" + Bits[ i ] + " tc=" + Codes[ i ].ToString("X") + " freq=" + Used[ i ] );

    return false;
  }

  private static int Reverse( int x, int bits )
  // Reverse a string of bits ( ready to be output as Huffman code ).
  { 
    int result = 0; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < bits; i += 1 ) 
    {
      result <<= 1; 
      result |= x & 1; 
      x >>= 1; 
    } 
    return result; 
  } 

  private abstract class TreeNode
  { 
    public int Used; 
    public byte Depth; 

    public static bool LessThan( TreeNode a, TreeNode b )
    { 
      return a.Used < b.Used || a.Used == b.Used && a.Depth < b.Depth;
    }

    public abstract void GetBits( byte [] nbits, int length );

  }

  private class Leaf : TreeNode
  {
    public ushort Code; 

    public Leaf( ushort code, int used )
    {
      Code = code;
      Used = used;
    }

    public override void GetBits( byte [] nbits, int length )
    { 
      nbits[ Code ] = (byte)length;
    }
  } // end class Leaf

  private class Branch : TreeNode
  {
    TreeNode Left, Right; 

    public Branch( TreeNode left, TreeNode right )
    {
      Left = left;
      Right = right;
      Used = left.Used + right.Used;
      Depth = (byte)( 1 + ( left.Depth > right.Depth ? left.Depth : right.Depth ) );
    }

    public override void GetBits( byte [] nbits, int length )
    { 
      Left.GetBits( nbits, length + 1 ); 
      Right.GetBits( nbits, length + 1 ); 
    }
  } // end class Branch

} // end struct HuffmanCoding


// ******************************************************************************


sealed class Heap<T> // An array organised so the smallest element can be efficiently removed.
{
  public delegate bool DLessThan( T a, T b );

  public int Count { get{ return _Count; } }
  private int _Count;
  private T [] Array;
  private DLessThan LessThan;

  public Heap ( int capacity, DLessThan lessThan )
  {
    Array = new T[ capacity ];
    LessThan = lessThan;
  }

  public void Insert( T e )
  {
    int j = _Count++;
    while ( j > 0 )
    {
      int p = ( j - 1 ) / 2; // Index of parent.
      T pe = Array[ p ];
      if ( !LessThan( e, pe ) ) break;
      Array[ j ] = pe; // Demote parent.
      j = p;
    }    
    Array[ j ] = e;
  }

  public T Remove() // Returns the smallest element.
  {
    T result = Array[ 0 ];
    _Count -= 1;
    T e = Array[ _Count ];
    Array[ _Count ] = default(T);
    int j = 0;
    while ( true )
    {
      int c = j * 2 + 1; if ( c >= _Count ) break;
      T ce = Array[ c ];
      if ( c + 1 < _Count )
      {
        T ce2 = Array[ c + 1 ];
        if ( LessThan( ce2, ce ) ) { c += 1; ce = ce2; }
      } 
      if ( !LessThan( ce, e ) ) break;
      Array[ j ] = ce; j = c;  
    }
    Array[ j ] = e;
    return result;
  }

} // end class Heap


// ******************************************************************************


abstract class OutBitStream
{
  public void WriteBits( int n, ulong value )
  // Write first n ( 0 <= n <= 64 ) bits of value to stream, least significant bit is written first.
  // Unused bits of value must be zero, i.e. value must be in range 0 .. 2^n-1.
  {
    if ( n + BitsInWord >= WordCapacity )
    {
      Save( Word | value << BitsInWord );
      int space = WordCapacity - BitsInWord;
      value >>= space;
      n -= space;
      Word = 0;
      BitsInWord = 0;
    }
    Word |= value << BitsInWord;
    BitsInWord += n;
  }

  public void Pad( int n )
  // Pad with zero bits to n bit boundary where n is power of 2 in range 1,2,4..64, typically n=8.
  {
    int w = BitsInWord % n; 
    if ( w > 0 ) WriteBits( n - w, 0 );
  }

  public abstract void Save( ulong word );

  protected const int WordSize = sizeof(ulong);  // Size of Word in bytes.
  protected const int WordCapacity = WordSize * 8; // Number of bits that can be stored Word

  protected ulong Word; // Bits are first stored in Word, when full, Word is saved.
  protected int BitsInWord; // Number of bits currently stored in Word.
}


// ******************************************************************************


sealed class MemoryBitStream : OutBitStream
{
  // ByteSize returns the current size in bytes.
  // CopyTo copies the contents to a Stream.
  // ToArray returns the contents as an array of bytes.

  public int ByteSize() 
  {
    return ( CompleteChunks * Chunk.Capacity + WordsInCurrentChunk ) * WordSize + ( BitsInWord + 7 ) / 8;
  }

  public void CopyTo( System.IO.Stream s ) 
  {
    byte [] buffer = new byte [ WordSize ];
    for ( Chunk c = FirstChunk; c != null; c = c.Next )
    { 
      int n = ( c == CurrentChunk ) ? WordsInCurrentChunk : Chunk.Capacity;
      for ( int j = 0; j < n; j += 1 ) 
      {
        ulong w = c.Words[ j ];
        unchecked
        {
          buffer[0] = (byte) w;
          buffer[1] = (byte)( w >> 8 );
          buffer[2] = (byte)( w >> 16 );
          buffer[3] = (byte)( w >> 24 );
          buffer[4] = (byte)( w >> 32 );
          buffer[5] = (byte)( w >> 40 );
          buffer[6] = (byte)( w >> 48 );
          buffer[7] = (byte)( w >> 56 );
        }
        s.Write( buffer, 0, 8 ); 
      }
    }

    int biw = BitsInWord;
    ulong word = Word;
    while ( biw > 0 )
    {
      s.WriteByte( unchecked( (byte) word ) );
      word >>= 8;
      biw -= 8;
    }
  }

  public byte [] ToArray()
  {
    byte [] buffer = new byte[ ByteSize() ];
    int i = 0;

    for ( Chunk c = FirstChunk; c != null; c = c.Next )
    { 
      int n = ( c == CurrentChunk ) ? WordsInCurrentChunk : Chunk.Capacity;
      for ( int j = 0; j < n; j += 1 ) 
      {
        ulong w = c.Words[ j ];
        unchecked
        {
          buffer[i++] = (byte) w;
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 8 );
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 16 );
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 24 );
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 32 );
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 40 );
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 48 );
          buffer[i++] = (byte)( w >> 56 );
        }
      }
    }

    int biw = BitsInWord;
    ulong word = Word;
    while ( biw > 0 )
    {
      buffer[ i++ ] = unchecked( (byte) word );
      word >>= 8;
      biw -= 8;
    }
    return buffer;
  }

  public MemoryBitStream()
  {
    FirstChunk = new Chunk();
    CurrentChunk = FirstChunk;
  }

  public override void Save( ulong word )
  {
    if ( WordsInCurrentChunk == Chunk.Capacity )
    {
      Chunk nc = new Chunk();
      CurrentChunk.Next = nc;
      CurrentChunk = nc;
      CompleteChunks += 1;
      WordsInCurrentChunk = 0;
    }
    CurrentChunk.Words[ WordsInCurrentChunk++ ] = word;
  }

  private int WordsInCurrentChunk; // Number of words stored in CurrentChunk.
  private int CompleteChunks; // Number of complete Chunks.
  private Chunk FirstChunk, CurrentChunk;

  private class Chunk
  {
    public const int Capacity = 256;
    public ulong [] Words = new ulong[ Capacity ];
    public Chunk Next;
  }

} // end class MemoryBitStream

} // namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not looked in detail at the interesting stuff, but a couple of tiny things jumped out at me:

## `CalcBufferSize`

This method looks wrong:

```
public static int CalcBufferSize( int n, int max )
// Calculates a power of 2 >= n, but not more than max.
{
  if ( n >= max ) return max;
  int result = 1;
  while ( result < n ) result = result << 1;
  return result;
}
```

The comment (or inline documentation) should probably explain here that you assume `max` is a power of two (because it doesn't work otherwise); this might cause confusion in the future otherwise. I see that you've made this method private in later revisions, so that's good.

## Heap Sort

I think your heap-sort in `PackageMerge` can be better. Repeated insertion is `O(n log(n))`, but you can build a heap from a known set of elements in linear time ([lazy Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap)), which is an option there (and I'm assuming you've benchmarked your own heap-sort against `Array.Sort` and such if this matters). I'd also feel compelled to add parentheses into `(ulong)Used[ i ] << IdBits | i )`, since both `<<` and `|` are uncommon operations and the order of operations may not be clear.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake that CalcBufferSize was public. On the sort, I used heapsort as I had it handy, I didn't know about Array.Sort ( which apparently uses heapsort or quicksort ). I will try that. I have done the linear heap build, which I didn't know about either.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of alternative ideas for dividing the input into blocks, I have now implemented a fairly simple extension : the code now checks whether moving data into the previous block improves compression (with the current encodings), before making a decision about doubling the block size.

The search terminates if a code is encountered which doesn't occur in the previous block ( this seems a reasonable heuristic, I guess it could assign a fairly large penalty and continue the search instead ).

Here's a copy of the revised code, the new function is `TuneBoundary`. The code incorporates various other improvements as well.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Pdf {

/* RFC 1951 compression ( https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt ) aims to compress a stream of bytes using :

   (1) LZ77 matching, where if an input sequences of at least 3 bytes re-occurs, it may be coded 
       as a <length,distance> pointer.

   (2) Huffman coding, where variable length codes are used, with more frequently used symbols encoded in less bits.

   The input may be split into blocks, a new block introduces a new set of Huffman codes. The choice of block 
   boundaries can affect compression. The method used to determine the block size is as follows:

   (1) The size of the next block to be output is set to an initial value.

   (2) A comparison is made between encoding two blocks of this size, or a double-length block.

   (3) If the double-length encoding is better, that becomes the block size, and the process repeats.

   LZ77 compression is implemented as suggested in the standard, although no attempt is made to
   truncate searches ( except searches terminate when the distance limit of 32k bytes is reached ).

   Only dynamic huffman blocks are used, no attempt is made to use Fixed or Copy blocks.

   Deflator ( this code) typically achieves better compression than ZLib ( http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm 
   via https://zlib.net/, default settings ) by a few percent, and is faster on small inputs, but slower 
   on large inputs.

   For example, compressing a font file FreeSans.ttf ( 264,072 bytes ), Zlib output is 148,324 bytes
   in 50 milliseconds, whereas Deflator output is 143,666 bytes in 58 milliseconds. If dynamic block sizing
   is disabled, the output is 146,892 bytes and the time is the same as ZLib.

   Compressing a C# source file of 19,483 bytes, Zlib output size is 5,965 bytes in 27 milliseconds, 
   whereas Deflator output is 5,890 bytes, 75 bytes smaller, in 16 milliseconds.

   Sample usage:

   byte [] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   var mbs = new MemoryBitStream();
   Deflator.Deflate( data, mbs, 1 );
   byte [] deflated_data = mbs.ToArray();

   The MemoryBitStream may alternatively be copied to a stream, this may be useful when writing PDF files ( the intended use case ).

   Auxiliary top level classes/structs ( included in this file ): 
   *  OutBitStream.
   *  MemoryBitStream : an implementation of OutBitStream.
   *  HuffmanCoding calculates Huffman codes.
   *  UlongHeap : used to implemnt HuffmanCoding.
*/   

sealed class Deflator 
{

  public static void Deflate( byte [] input, OutBitStream output )  // Deflate with default options.
  {
    Deflator d = new Deflator( input, output );
    d.Go();
  }

  // Options : to amend these use new Deflator( input, output ) and set before calling Go().
  public int StartBlockSize = 0x1000; // Increase to go faster ( with less compression ), reduce to try for more compression.
  public int MaxBufferSize = 0x8000; // Must be power of 2, increase to try for slightly more compression on large inputs.
  public bool RFC1950 = true; // Set false to suppress RFC 1950 fields.
  public bool LZ77 = true; // Set false to go much faster ( with much less compression ).
  public bool DynamicBlockSize = true; // Set false to go faster ( with less compression ).
  public bool TuneBlockSize = true; // Set false to go faster ( with less compression ).

  public Deflator( byte [] input, OutBitStream output )
  { 
    Input = input; 
    Output = output; 
  }

  public void Go()
  {
    int bufferSize = CalcBufferSize( Input.Length / 3, MaxBufferSize );
    PositionBuffer = new int[ bufferSize ];
    LengthBuffer   = new byte[ bufferSize ];
    DistanceBuffer = new ushort[ bufferSize ];   
    BufferMask = bufferSize - 1; 

    if ( RFC1950 ) Output.WriteBits( 16, 0x9c78 );
    if ( LZ77 ) FindMatches( Input );
    Buffered = Input.Length;
    while ( !OutputBlock( true ) );
    if ( RFC1950 )
    { 
      Output.Pad( 8 );
      Output.WriteBits( 32, Adler32( Input ) );
    } 
  }

  // Private constants.

  // RFC 1951 limits.
  private const int MinMatch = 3;
  private const int MaxMatch = 258;
  private const int MaxDistance = 0x8000;

  // Instead of initialising LZ77 hashTable and link arrays to -(MaxDistance+1), EncodePosition 
  // is added when storing a value and subtracted when retrieving a value.
  // This means a default value of 0 will always be more distant than MaxDistance.
  private const int EncodePosition = MaxDistance + 1;

  // Private fields.

  private byte [] Input;
  private OutBitStream Output;

  private int Buffered; // How many Input bytes have been processed to intermediate buffer.
  private int Finished; // How many Input bytes have been written to Output.

  // Intermediate circular buffer for storing LZ77 matches.
  private int    [] PositionBuffer;
  private byte   [] LengthBuffer;
  private ushort [] DistanceBuffer;
  private int BufferMask;
  private int BufferWrite, BufferRead; // Indexes for writing and reading.

  // Private functions and classes.

  private static int CalcBufferSize( int n, int max )
  // Calculates a power of 2 >= n, but not more than max.
  {
    if ( n >= max ) return max;
    int result = 1;
    while ( result < n ) result = result << 1;
    return result;
  }

  private void FindMatches( byte [] input ) // LZ77 compression.
  {
    if ( input.Length < MinMatch ) return;
    int limit = input.Length - 2;

    int hashShift = CalcHashShift( limit * 2 );
    uint hashMask = ( 1u << ( MinMatch * hashShift ) ) - 1;

    int [] hashTable = new int[ hashMask + 1 ];
    int [] link = new int[ limit ];

    int position = 0; // position in input.
    uint hash = ( (uint)input[ 0 ] << hashShift ) + input[ 1 ];

    while ( position < limit )
    {
      hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;        
      int hashEntry = hashTable[ hash ];
      hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
      if ( position >= hashEntry ) // Equivalent to position - ( hashEntry - EncodePosition ) > MaxDistance.
      {
         position += 1;
         continue;
      }
      link[ position ] = hashEntry;

      int distance, match = BestMatch( input, link, hashEntry - EncodePosition, position, out distance );
      position += 1;
      if ( match < MinMatch ) continue;

      // "Lazy matching" RFC 1951 p.15 : if there are overlapping matches, there is a choice over which of the match to use.
      // Example: "abc012bc345.... abc345". Here abc345 can be encoded as either [abc][345] or as a[bc345].
      // Since a range typically needs more bits to encode than a single literal, choose the latter.
      while ( position < limit ) 
      {
        hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;          
        hashEntry = hashTable[ hash ];
        hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
        if ( position >= hashEntry ) break;
        link[ position ] = hashEntry;

        int distance2, match2 = BestMatch( input, link, hashEntry - EncodePosition, position, out distance2 );
        if ( match2 > match || match2 == match && distance2 < distance )
        {
          match = match2;
          distance = distance2;
          position += 1;
        }
        else break;
      }

      int copyEnd = SaveMatch( position - 1, match, distance );
      if ( copyEnd > limit ) copyEnd = limit;

      position += 1;

      // Advance to end of copied section.
      while ( position < copyEnd )
      { 
        hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;
        link[ position ] = hashTable[ hash ];
        hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
        position += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  private static int BestMatch( byte [] input, int [] link, int oldPosition, int position, out int distance )
  { 
    int avail = input.Length - position;
    if ( avail > MaxMatch ) avail = MaxMatch;

    int bestMatch = 0, bestDistance = 0;

    while ( true )
    { 
      if ( input[ position + bestMatch ] == input[ oldPosition + bestMatch ] )
      {
        int match = 0;  
        while ( match < avail && input[ position + match ] == input[ oldPosition + match ] ) 
          match += 1;

        if ( match > bestMatch )
        {
          bestMatch = match;
          bestDistance = position - oldPosition;
          if ( bestMatch == avail ) break;
        }
      }
      oldPosition = link[ oldPosition ];
      if ( position >= oldPosition ) break;
      oldPosition -= EncodePosition;
    }
    distance = bestDistance;
    return bestMatch;
  }

  private static int CalcHashShift( int n )
  {
    int p = 1;
    int result = 0;
    while ( n > p ) 
    {
      p = p << MinMatch;
      result += 1;
      if ( result == 6 ) break;
    }
    return result;
  } 

  private int SaveMatch ( int position, int length, int distance )
  // Called from FindMatches to save a <length,distance> match. Returns position + length.
  {
    // System.Console.WriteLine( "SaveMatch at " + position + " length=" + length + " distance=" + distance );
    int i = BufferWrite;
    PositionBuffer[ i ] = position;
    LengthBuffer[ i ] = (byte) (length - MinMatch);
    DistanceBuffer[ i ] = (ushort) distance;
    i = ( i + 1 ) & BufferMask;
    if ( i == BufferRead ) OutputBlock( false );
    BufferWrite = i;
    position += length;
    Buffered = position;
    return position;
  }

  private bool OutputBlock( bool last )
  {
    int blockSize = Buffered - Finished; // Uncompressed size in bytes.

    if ( blockSize > StartBlockSize ) 
    {
      blockSize = ( last && blockSize < StartBlockSize*2 ) ? blockSize >> 1 : StartBlockSize;
    }

    Block b = new Block( this, blockSize, null );
    int bits = b.GetBits(); // Compressed size in bits.
    int finalBlockSize = blockSize;

    // Investigate larger block size.
    while ( b.End < Buffered && DynamicBlockSize ) 
    {
      // b2 is a block which starts just after b.
      Block b2 = new Block( this, blockSize, b );

      // b3 covers b and b2 exactly as one block.
      Block b3 = new Block( this, b2.End - b.Start, null );

      int bits2 = b2.GetBits();
      int bits3 = b3.GetBits(); 

      int delta = TuneBlockSize ? b2.TuneBoundary( this, b, blockSize / 4, out finalBlockSize ) : 0;

      if ( bits3 > bits + bits2 + delta ) break;

      bits = bits3;
      b = b3;
      blockSize += blockSize; 
      finalBlockSize = blockSize;
    }      

    if ( finalBlockSize > blockSize )
    {
      b = new Block( this, finalBlockSize, null ); 
      b.GetBits();
    }

    // Output the block.
    if ( b.End < Buffered ) last = false;
    b.WriteBlock( this, last );  
    return last;
  }

  public static uint Adler32( byte [] b ) // Checksum function per RFC 1950.
  {
    uint s1 = 1, s2 = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < b.Length; i += 1 )
    {
      s1 = ( s1 + b[ i ] ) % 65521;
      s2 = ( s2 + s1 ) % 65521;
    }
    return s2 * 65536 + s1;    
  }

  private class Block
  {
    public readonly int Start, End; // Range of input encoded.

    public Block( Deflator d, int blockSize, Block previous )
    // The block is not immediately output, to allow caller to try different block sizes.
    // Instead, the number of bits neeed to encoded the block is returned by GetBits ( excluding "extra" bits ).
    {
      Output = d.Output;

      if ( previous == null )
      {
        Start = d.Finished;
        BufferStart = d.BufferRead;
      }
      else
      {
        Start = previous.End;
        BufferStart = previous.BufferEnd;
      }

      int avail = d.Buffered - Start;
      if ( blockSize > avail ) blockSize = avail;

      End = TallyFrequencies( d, blockSize );
      Lit.Used[ 256 ] += 1; // End of block code.
    }

    public int GetBits()
    {
      Lit.ComputeCodes();
      Dist.ComputeCodes();

      if ( Dist.Count == 0 ) Dist.Count = 1;

      // Compute length encoding.
      DoLengthPass( 1 );
      Len.ComputeCodes();

      // The length codes are permuted before being stored ( so that # of trailing zeroes is likely to be more ).
      Len.Count = 19; while ( Len.Count > 4 && Len.Bits[ ClenAlphabet[ Len.Count - 1 ] ] == 0 ) Len.Count -= 1;

      return 17 + 3 * Len.Count + Len.Total() + Lit.Total() + Dist.Total();
    }

    public void WriteBlock( Deflator d, bool last )
    {
      OutBitStream output = Output;
      output.WriteBits( 1, last ? 1u : 0u );
      output.WriteBits( 2, 2 );
      output.WriteBits( 5, (uint)( Lit.Count - 257 ) ); 
      output.WriteBits( 5, (uint)( Dist.Count - 1 ) ); 
      output.WriteBits( 4, (uint)( Len.Count - 4 ) );

      for ( int i = 0; i < Len.Count; i += 1 ) 
        output.WriteBits( 3, Len.Bits[ ClenAlphabet[ i ] ] );

      DoLengthPass( 2 );
      PutCodes( d );
      output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ 256 ], Lit.Codes[ 256 ] ); // End of block code
    }

    // Block private fields and constants.

    private OutBitStream Output;
    private int BufferStart, BufferEnd;

    // Huffman codings : Lit = Literal or Match Code, Dist = Distance code, Len = Length code.
    HuffmanCoding Lit = new HuffmanCoding(15,288), Dist = new HuffmanCoding(15,32), Len = new HuffmanCoding(7,19);

    // Counts for code length encoding.
    private int LengthPass, PreviousLength, ZeroRun, Repeat;

    // RFC 1951 constants.
    private readonly static byte [] ClenAlphabet = { 16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15 };
    private readonly static byte [] MatchExtra = { 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 0 };
    private readonly static ushort [] MatchOff = { 3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10, 11,13,15,17, 19,23,27,31, 35,43,51,59, 67,83,99,115, 
      131,163,195,227, 258, 0xffff };
    private readonly static byte [] DistExtra = { 0,0,0,0, 1,1,2,2, 3,3,4,4, 5,5,6,6, 7,7,8,8, 9,9,10,10, 11,11,12,12, 13,13 };
    private readonly static ushort [] DistOff = { 1,2,3,4, 5,7,9,13, 17,25,33,49, 65,97,129,193, 257,385,513,769, 
      1025,1537,2049,3073, 4097,6145,8193,12289, 16385,24577, 0xffff };

    // Block private functions.

    private int TallyFrequencies( Deflator d, int blockSize )
    {
      int position = Start;
      int end = position + blockSize;

      int bufferRead = BufferStart;
      while ( position < end && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        if ( matchPosition >= end ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ] + MinMatch;
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        bufferRead = ( bufferRead + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        byte [] input = d.Input;
        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          Lit.Used[ input[ position ] ] += 1;
          position += 1;
        }

        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        Lit.Used[ 257 + mc ] += 1;
        Dist.Used[ dc ] += 1;     
      }

      while ( position < end ) 
      {
        Lit.Used[ d.Input[ position ] ] += 1;
        position += 1;
      }

      BufferEnd = bufferRead;
      return position;
    }

    public int TuneBoundary( Deflator d, Block prev, int howfar, out int blockSize )
    {
      // Investigate whether moving data into the previous block uses fewer bits,
      // using the current encodings. If a symbol with no encoding in the 
      // previous block is found, terminate the search ( goto EndSearch ).

      int position = Start;
      int bufferRead = BufferStart;
      int end = position + howfar;
      if ( end > End ) end = End;

      int delta = 0, bestDelta = 0, bestPosition = position;

      while ( position < End && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];

        if ( matchPosition >= End ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ] + MinMatch;
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead  ]; 

        bufferRead = ( bufferRead  + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          byte b = d.Input[ position ];

          if ( prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] == 0 ) goto EndSearch;
          delta += prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] - Lit.Bits[ b ];
          if ( delta < bestDelta ) { bestDelta = delta; bestPosition = position; }
          position += 1;
        }  
        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        if ( prev.Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ] == 0 || prev.Dist.Bits[ dc ] == 0 ) goto EndSearch;
        delta += prev.Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ] - Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc  ];
        delta += prev.Dist.Bits[ dc ] - Dist.Bits[ dc ];

        if ( delta < bestDelta ) { bestDelta = delta; bestPosition = position; }
        position += 1;
      }

      while ( position < end ) 
      {
        byte b = d.Input[ position ];
        if ( prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] == 0 ) goto EndSearch;
        delta += prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] - Lit.Bits[ b ];
        if ( delta < bestDelta ) { bestDelta = delta; bestPosition = position; }
        position += 1;
      }  

      EndSearch:

      blockSize = bestPosition - prev.Start;
      return bestDelta;
    }


    private void PutCodes( Deflator d )
    {
      byte [] input = d.Input;
      OutBitStream output = d.Output;

      int position = Start;
      int bufferRead = BufferStart;

      while ( position < End && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];

        if ( matchPosition >= End ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ] + MinMatch;
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead  ]; 

        bufferRead = ( bufferRead  + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          byte b = d.Input[ position ];
          output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ b ], Lit.Codes[ b ] );
          position += 1;
        }  
        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ], Lit.Codes[ 257 + mc ] );
        output.WriteBits( MatchExtra[ mc ], (uint)(length-MatchOff[ mc ] ) );
        output.WriteBits( Dist.Bits[ dc ], Dist.Codes[ dc ] );
        output.WriteBits( DistExtra[ dc ], (uint)(distance-DistOff[ dc ] ) );    
      }

      while ( position < End ) 
      {
        byte b = input[ position ];
        output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ b ], Lit.Codes[ b ] );
        position += 1;
      }  

      d.BufferRead = bufferRead;
      d.Finished = position;
    }

    // Run length encoding of code lengths - RFC 1951, page 13.

    private void DoLengthPass( int pass )
    {
      LengthPass = pass; 
      EncodeLengths( Lit.Count, Lit.Bits, true );     
      EncodeLengths( Dist.Count, Dist.Bits, false );
    }

    private void PutLength( int code ) 
    { 
      if ( LengthPass == 1 ) 
        Len.Used[ code ] += 1; 
      else 
        Output.WriteBits( Len.Bits[ code ], Len.Codes[ code ] ); 
    }

    private void EncodeLengths( int n, byte [] lengths, bool isLit )
    {
      if ( isLit ) 
      { 
        PreviousLength = 0; 
        ZeroRun = 0; 
        Repeat = 0; 
      }
      for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 1 )
      {
        int length = lengths[ i ];
        if ( length == 0 )
        { 
          EncodeRepeat(); 
          ZeroRun += 1; 
          PreviousLength = 0; 
        }
        else if ( length == PreviousLength ) 
        {
          Repeat += 1;
        }
        else 
        { 
          EncodeZeroRun(); 
          EncodeRepeat(); 
          PutLength( length ); 
          PreviousLength = length; 
        }
      }      
      if ( !isLit ) 
      { 
        EncodeZeroRun(); 
        EncodeRepeat();
      }
    }

    private void EncodeRepeat()
    {
      while ( Repeat > 0 )
      {
        if ( Repeat < 3 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( PreviousLength ); 
          Repeat -= 1; 
        }
        else 
        { 
          int x = Repeat; 
          if ( x > 6 ) x = 6; 
          PutLength( 16 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 )
          { 
            Output.WriteBits( 2, (uint)( x - 3 ) ); 
          }
          Repeat -= x;  
        }
      }
    }

    private void EncodeZeroRun()
    {
      while ( ZeroRun > 0 )
      {
        if ( ZeroRun < 3 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( 0 ); 
          ZeroRun -= 1; 
        }
        else if ( ZeroRun < 11 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( 17 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 ) Output.WriteBits( 3, (uint)( ZeroRun - 3 ) ); 
          ZeroRun = 0;  
        }
        else 
        { 
          int x = ZeroRun; 
          if ( x > 138 ) x = 138; 
          PutLength( 18 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 ) Output.WriteBits( 7, (uint)( x - 11 ) ); 
          ZeroRun -= x; 
        }
      }
    }
  } // end class Block

} // end class Deflator


// ******************************************************************************

struct HuffmanCoding // Variable length coding.
{
  public ushort Count; // Number of symbols.
  public byte [] Bits; // Number of bits used to encode a symbol ( code length ).
  public ushort [] Codes; // Huffman code for a symbol ( bit 0 is most significant ).
  public int [] Used; // Count of how many times a symbol is used in the block being encoded.

  private int Limit; // Limit on code length ( 15 or 7 for RFC 1951 ).
  private ushort [] Left, Right; // Tree storage.

  public HuffmanCoding( int limit, ushort symbols )
  {
    Limit = limit;
    Count = symbols;
    Bits = new byte[ symbols ];
    Codes = new ushort[ symbols ];
    Used = new int[ symbols ];
    Left = new ushort[ symbols ];
    Right = new ushort[ symbols ];
  }

  public int Total()
  {
    int result = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
      result += Used[i] * Bits[i];
    return result;
  }

  public void ComputeCodes()
  {
    // Tree nodes are encoded in a ulong using 16 bits for the id, 8 bits for the tree depth, 32 bits for Used.
    const int IdBits = 16, DepthBits = 8, UsedBits = 32;
    const uint IdMask = ( 1u << IdBits ) - 1;
    const uint DepthOne = 1u << IdBits;
    const uint DepthMask = ( ( 1u << DepthBits ) - 1 ) << IdBits;
    const ulong UsedMask = ( ( 1ul << UsedBits ) - 1 ) << ( IdBits + DepthBits );

    // First compute the number of bits to encode each symbol (Bits).
    UlongHeap heap = new UlongHeap( Count );

    for ( ushort i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 )
    {
      int used = Used[ i ];
      if ( used > 0 )
        heap.Insert( ( (ulong)used << ( IdBits + DepthBits ) ) | i );
    }

    int maxBits = 0;

    if ( heap.Count == 1 )
    { 
      GetBits( unchecked( (ushort) heap.Remove() ), 1 );
      maxBits = 1;
    }
    else if ( heap.Count > 1 ) unchecked
    {
      ulong treeNode = Count;

      do // Keep pairing the lowest frequency TreeNodes.
      {
        ulong left = heap.Remove(); 
        Left[ treeNode - Count ] = (ushort) left;

        ulong right = heap.Remove(); 
        Right[ treeNode - Count ] = (ushort) right;

        // Extract depth of left and right nodes ( still shifted though ).
        uint depthLeft = (uint)left & DepthMask, depthRight = (uint)right & DepthMask; 

        // New node depth is 1 + larger of depthLeft and depthRight.
        uint depth = ( depthLeft > depthRight ? depthLeft : depthRight ) + DepthOne;

        heap.Insert( ( ( left + right ) & UsedMask ) | depth | treeNode );

        treeNode += 1;
      }  while ( heap.Count > 1 );

      uint root = ( (uint) heap.Remove() ) & ( DepthMask | IdMask );
      maxBits = (int)( root >> IdBits );
      if ( maxBits <= Limit )
        GetBits( (ushort)root, 0 );
      else
      {
        maxBits = Limit;
        PackageMerge();
      }
    }

    // Computation of code lengths (Bits) is complete.
    // Now compute Codes, code below is from RFC 1951 page 7.

    int [] bl_count = new int[ maxBits + 1 ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
      bl_count[ Bits[ i ] ] += 1; 

    int [] next_code = new int[ maxBits + 1 ];
    int code = 0; bl_count[ 0 ] = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxBits; i += 1 ) 
    {
      code = ( code + bl_count[ i ] ) << 1;
      next_code[ i + 1 ] = code;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
    {
      int length = Bits[ i ];
      if ( length != 0 ) 
      {
        Codes[ i ] = (ushort) Reverse( next_code[ length ], length );
        next_code[ length ] += 1;
      }
    }

    // Reduce Count if there are unused trailing symbols.
    while ( Count > 0 && Bits[ Count - 1 ] == 0 ) Count -= 1;

    // System.Console.WriteLine( "HuffmanCoding.ComputeCodes" );
    //   for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) if ( Bits[ i ] > 0 )
    //     System.Console.WriteLine( "symbol=" + i + " len=" + Bits[ i ] + " code=" + Codes[ i ].ToString("X") + " used=" + Used[ i ] );

  }

  private void GetBits( ushort treeNode, int length )
  {
    if ( treeNode < Count ) // treeNode is a leaf.
    {
      Bits[ treeNode ] = (byte)length;
    }
    else 
    {
      treeNode -= Count;
      length += 1;
      GetBits( Left[ treeNode ], length );
      GetBits( Right[ treeNode ], length );
    }
  }

  private static int Reverse( int x, int bits )
  // Reverse a string of bits ( ready to be output as Huffman code ).
  { 
    int result = 0; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < bits; i += 1 ) 
    {
      result <<= 1; 
      result |= x & 1; 
      x >>= 1; 
    } 
    return result; 
  } 

  // PackageMerge is used if the Limit code length limit is exceeded.
  // The result is technically not a Huffman code in this case ( due to the imposed limit ).
  // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package-merge_algorithm for a description of the algorithm.

  private void PackageMerge()
  {
    // Tree nodes are encoded in a ulong using 16 bits for the id, 32 bits for Used.
    const int IdBits = 16, UsedBits = 32;
    const ulong UsedMask = ( ( 1ul << UsedBits ) - 1 ) << IdBits;

    Left = new ushort[ Count * Limit ];
    Right = new ushort[ Count * Limit ];

    // First sort using Heapsort.
    UlongHeap heap = new UlongHeap( Count );
    for ( uint i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
    {
      if ( Used[ i ] != 0 ) 
      {
        heap.Insert( (ulong)Used[ i ] << IdBits | i );
      }
    }
    int n = heap.Count; 
    ulong [] sorted = new ulong[ n ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 1 ) sorted[ i ] = heap.Remove();

    // Sort is complete.

    // List class is from System.Collections.Generic.
    List<ulong> merged = new List<ulong>( Count ), 
                next = new List<ulong>( Count );

    uint package = (uint) Count; // Allocator for package ids.

    for ( int i = 0; i < Limit; i += 1 ) 
    {
      int j = 0, k = 0; // Indexes into the lists being merged.
      next.Clear();
      for ( int total = ( sorted.Length + merged.Count ) / 2; total > 0; total -= 1 )  
      {
        ulong left, right; // The tree nodes to be packaged.

        if ( k < merged.Count )
        {
          left = merged[ k ];
          if ( j < sorted.Length )
          {
            ulong sj = sorted[ j ];
            if ( left < sj ) k += 1;
            else { left = sj; j += 1; }
          }
          else k += 1;
        }
        else left = sorted[ j++ ];

        if ( k < merged.Count )
        {
          right = merged[ k ];
          if ( j < sorted.Length )
          {
            ulong sj = sorted[ j ];
            if ( right < sj ) k += 1;
            else { right = sj; j += 1; }
          }
          else k += 1;
        }
        else right = sorted[ j++ ];

        Left[ package ] = unchecked( (ushort) left );
        Right[ package ] = unchecked( (ushort) right );
        next.Add( ( left + right ) & UsedMask | package );        
        package += 1;
      }

      // Swap merged and next.
      List<ulong> tmp = merged; merged = next; next = tmp;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < merged.Count; i += 1 )
      MergeGetBits( unchecked( (ushort) merged[i] ) );
  }

  private void MergeGetBits( ushort node )
  {
    if ( node < Count )
      Bits[ node ] += 1;
    else
    {
      MergeGetBits( Left[ node ] );
      MergeGetBits( Right[ node ] );
    }
  }

} // end struct HuffmanCoding


// ******************************************************************************


struct UlongHeap // An array organised so the smallest element can be efficiently removed.
{
  public int Count { get{ return _Count; } }
  private int _Count;
  private ulong [] Array;

  public UlongHeap ( int capacity )
  {
    _Count = 0;
    Array = new ulong[ capacity ];
  }

  public void Insert( ulong e )
  {
    int j = _Count++;
    while ( j > 0 )
    {
      int p = ( j - 1 ) >> 1; // Index of parent.
      ulong pe = Array[ p ];
      if ( e >= pe ) break;
      Array[ j ] = pe; // Demote parent.
      j = p;
    }    
    Array[ j ] = e;
  }

  public ulong Remove() // Returns the smallest element.
  {
    ulong result = Array[ 0 ];
    _Count -= 1;
    ulong e = Array[ _Count ];
    int j = 0;
    while ( true )
    {
      int c = ( j + j ) + 1; if ( c >= _Count ) break;
      ulong ce = Array[ c ];
      if ( c + 1 < _Count )
      {
        ulong ce2 = Array[ c + 1 ];
        if ( ce2 < ce ) { c += 1; ce = ce2; }
      } 
      if ( ce >= e ) break;
      Array[ j ] = ce; j = c;  
    }
    Array[ j ] = e;
    return result;
  }

} // end struct UlongHeap


// ******************************************************************************


abstract class OutBitStream
{
  public void WriteBits( int n, ulong value )
  // Write first n ( 0 <= n <= 64 ) bits of value to stream, least significant bit is written first.
  // Unused bits of value must be zero, i.e. value must be in range 0 .. 2^n-1.
  {
    if ( n + BitsInWord >= WordCapacity )
    {
      Save( Word | value << BitsInWord );
      int space = WordCapacity - BitsInWord;
      value >>= space;
      n -= space;
      Word = 0;
      BitsInWord = 0;
    }
    Word |= value << BitsInWord;
    BitsInWord += n;
  }

  public void Pad( int n )
  // Pad with zero bits to n bit boundary where n is power of 2 in range 1,2,4..64, typically n=8.
  {
    int w = BitsInWord % n; 
    if ( w > 0 ) WriteBits( n - w, 0 );
  }

  public abstract void Save( ulong word );

  protected const int WordSize = sizeof(ulong);  // Size of Word in bytes.
  protected const int WordCapacity = WordSize * 8; // Number of bits that can be stored Word

  protected ulong Word; // Bits are first stored in Word, when full, Word is saved.
  protected int BitsInWord; // Number of bits currently stored in Word.
}


// ******************************************************************************


sealed class MemoryBitStream : OutBitStream
{
  // ByteSize returns the current size in bytes.
  // CopyTo copies the contents to a Stream.
  // ToArray returns the contents as an array of bytes.

  public int ByteSize() 
  {
    return CompleteChunks * Chunk.Capacity + BytesInCurrentChunk + ( BitsInWord + 7 ) / 8;
  }

  public void CopyTo( System.IO.Stream s ) 
  {
    byte [] buffer = new byte [ WordSize ];
    for ( Chunk c = FirstChunk; c != null; c = c.Next )
    { 
      int n = ( c == CurrentChunk ) ? BytesInCurrentChunk : Chunk.Capacity;
      s.Write( c.Bytes, 0, n ); 
    }

    int biw = BitsInWord;
    ulong word = Word;
    while ( biw > 0 )
    {
      s.WriteByte( unchecked( (byte) word ) );
      word >>= 8;
      biw -= 8;
    }
  }

  public byte [] ToArray()
  {
    byte [] buffer = new byte[ ByteSize() ];
    int i = 0;

    for ( Chunk c = FirstChunk; c != null; c = c.Next )
    { 
      int n = ( c == CurrentChunk ) ? BytesInCurrentChunk : Chunk.Capacity;
      System.Array.Copy( c.Bytes, 0, buffer, i, n ); 
      i += n;
    }

    int biw = BitsInWord;
    ulong word = Word;
    while ( biw > 0 )
    {
      buffer[ i++ ] = unchecked( (byte) word );
      word >>= 8;
      biw -= 8;
    }
    return buffer;
  }

  public MemoryBitStream()
  {
    FirstChunk = new Chunk();
    CurrentChunk = FirstChunk;
  }

  public override void Save( ulong w )
  {
    if ( BytesInCurrentChunk == Chunk.Capacity )
    {
      Chunk nc = new Chunk();
      CurrentChunk.Next = nc;
      CurrentChunk = nc;
      CompleteChunks += 1;
      BytesInCurrentChunk = 0;
    }
    int i = BytesInCurrentChunk;
    byte [] bytes = CurrentChunk.Bytes;
    unchecked
    {
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w;
    }
    BytesInCurrentChunk = i;
  }

  private int BytesInCurrentChunk; // Number of bytes stored in CurrentChunk.
  private int CompleteChunks; // Number of complete Chunks.
  private Chunk FirstChunk, CurrentChunk;

  private class Chunk
  {
    public const int Capacity = 0x800;
    public byte [] Bytes = new byte[ Capacity ];
    public Chunk Next;
  }

} // end class MemoryBitStream

} // namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a new trick which speeds up the LZ77 search.

After finding a match, it's possible to check the hash table for the last 3 bytes of the next largest possible match. If the hash entry is zero ( or earlier than the 32k window ), the search can be terminated. Here's the affected code, the new function is `MatchPossible`.

```
  private int BestMatch( byte [] input, int position, out int distance, int oldPosition, int [] link )
  { 
    int avail = input.Length - position;
    if ( avail > MaxMatch ) avail = MaxMatch;

    int bestMatch = 0, bestDistance = 0;

    while ( true )
    { 
      if ( input[ position + bestMatch ] == input[ oldPosition + bestMatch ] )
      {
        int match = 0; 
        while ( match < avail && input[ position + match ] == input[ oldPosition + match ] ) 
        {
          match += 1;
        }
        if ( match > bestMatch )
        {
          bestMatch = match;
          bestDistance = position - oldPosition;
          if ( bestMatch == avail ) break;
          if ( ! MatchPossible( position, bestMatch+1 ) ) break;
        }
      }
      oldPosition = link[ oldPosition ];
      if ( position >= oldPosition ) break;
      oldPosition -= EncodePosition;
    }
    distance = bestDistance;
    return bestMatch;
  }

  // MatchPossible is used to try and shorten the BestMatch search by checking whether 
  // there is a hash entry for the last 3 bytes of the next longest possible match.

  private bool MatchPossible( int position, int matchLength )
  {
    int end = position + matchLength - 3;
    uint hash = ( (uint)Input[ end+0 ] << HashShift ) + Input[ end+1 ];
    hash = ( ( hash << HashShift ) + Input[ end + 2 ] ) & HashMask;        
    int hashEntry = HashTable[ hash ];
    if ( end >= hashEntry ) return false;
    return true;
  }
```